# Python 3 httplib2 cookies

Tags: python, cookies, python-3.x, httplib2

Fixed, httplin2 can't handle more than one cookie, the patch can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/issues/detail?id=146

> I am coding a facebook login script to get my last notifications but
>   I'm having a problem. I've changed from urllib to httplib2 because it
>   seemed easier and faster to me. Using the urllib I was able to get the
>   correct cookie and use it when ever I needed to retrieve the
>   notifications, now I'm using the example from the httplib page:
>
> ```
> user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; zh-CN;
> ```
>
> rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8'
>       headers = {'User-Agent' : user_agent, 'Content-type':
>   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept' :
>   'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
>   'Connection' : 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
>   'Referer' : 'http://m.facebook.com/' }
>       data = {'email' : 'myusername', 'pass' : 'mypassword',
>   'post_form_id' : '', 'charset_test' : '', 'version': 1, 'ajax' : 1,
>   'pxr' : 1, 'gps' : 1, 'login' : 'Entrar'}
>       response, content =
>   h.request("http://www.facebook.com/login.php?m=m&refsrc=http://m.facebook.com/&refid=0",
>   "POST", urllib.parse.urlencode(data), headers=headers)
>
> And this is the header I'm getting:
>
> ```
> {'status': '200', 'x-cnection': 'close', 'content-location':
> ```
>
> 'http://m.facebook.com/home.php?refsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2F&refid=0&m_sess=*****tAm60&_rdr',
>   'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'set-cookie':
>   'datr=**********F-OQsTCnbw0Caa; expires=Fri, 06-Sep-2013 20:33:26 GMT;
>   path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly', 'expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000
>   00:00:00 GMT', 'x-fb-server': '10.62.188.41', 'content-length':
>   '26702', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'pragma': 'no-cache',
>   'cache-control': 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
>   'date': 'Wed, 07 Sep 2011 20:33:27 GMT', 'p3p': 'CP="Facebook does not
>   have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"', 'content-type':
>   'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'x-frame-options': 'DENY'}
>
> If I don't use the h.follow_all_redirects = True option, it doesn't
>   redirect me to the home page, but the set cookies are on the first
>   page before redirecting. The cookies I get are: `set-cookie':
>   'datr=F*******F-OQsTCnbw0Caa; expires=Fri, 06-Sep-2013 20:33:26 GMT;
>   path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly'`
>
> But those cookies aren't enough to get the session active. In the
>   browser I'm getting a larger cookie:
>
> ```
> datr=EzIL*********e-JFJL; lu=wgrr3q**********; locale=es_LA; L=2;
> ```
>
> act=13*************;
>   m_user=*********%40gmail.com%3A526402587%3AN************%3A0%3Av_1%2Cajax_1%2Cwidth_1600%2Cpxr_1%2Cgps_1%3A13******1099;
>   p=182; fl=1; W=13*******99;
>   reg_fb_ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flogin.php%3Fm%3Dm%26refsrc%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fm.facebook.com%252F%26refid%3D0
>
> What could be the problem?

Comment: If it's "fixed", don't edit it in the question, post an answer on your own question (and accept it).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, httplin2 can't handle more than one cookie, the patch can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/issues/detail?id=146